# How to get SUM of a column of a child table when query parent table?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two tables

Account Table (account)

```
id      name
1       Account 1
2       Account 2
3       Account 3
4       Account 2
```

Transaction Table (transaction)

```
id      account_id     type      amount     datetime
1       1              credit    500        2020-04-01 06:00:00
2       1              credit    300        2020-04-01 06:00:00
3       2              credit    100        2020-04-01 06:00:00
4       2              debit     50         2020-04-01 06:00:00
5       1              debit     600        2020-04-01 06:00:00
6       3              credit    1000       2020-04-01 06:00:00
7       1              credit    100
```

My target is to get account `id, name, balance` in one query. The balance will be calculated from the transaction table as `SUM of Credit Amount - SUM of Debit Amount` for a given account.

Target Output

```
   id      name          balance
   1       Account 1     300
   2       Account 2     50
   3       Account 3     1000
   4       Account 4     0
```

Possible Query

```
SELECT id, name, ((SELECT SUM(amount) FROM transaction WHERE type = 'credit' AND account_id = {ACCOUNT_ID} ) - (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM transaction WHERE type = 'debit' AND account_id = {ACCOUNT_ID} )) as balance
```

Is it possible to do this in one query and If yes How to do it.

Comment: Yes it is, You are using aggregate functions but not group by any reason for that?  And you should also read up on left join and coalesce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the aggregation in a derived table to avoid the issues of having to group by a lot of fields in the top level. For example:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, COALESCE(b.balance, 0) AS balance
FROM account a
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT account_id,
         SUM(CASE WHEN type='credit' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) -
         SUM(CASE WHEN type='debit' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS balance
  FROM transaction
  GROUP BY account_id
) b ON b.account_id = a.id
```

Output:

```
id  name        balance
1   Account 1   300
2   Account 2   50
3   Account 3   1000
4   Account 2   0
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3932f1/2)

Answer (score 0):

You need a `left join` of `account` to `transaction` so you can group by each account and conditionally sum the `amount` depending on the `type`:

```
select 
  a.id, a.name,
  sum(case when type = 'credit' then 1 else -1 end * coalesce(t.amount, 0)) balance
from account a left join transaction t
on t.account_id = a.id
group by a.id, a.name
```

Comment: Is it possible to wildcard the group by columns, because I have more than 60 columns in my account table

Comment: No you must write all the columns in the group by clause, unless you disable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` and then you can only group by a.id.  You can find more here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html